# Make URL be title of post

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes, format

Currently my URL's appear as `www.website.com/entries/1`, I'd like to make them appear as `www.website.com/title-of-entry`.  I've been messing around with `routes` and have been able to get the `entry` title to display in the URL, but Rails is unable to find the `entry` without supplying an ID.  If I send the ID along with the parameters, the URL appears as `www.website.com/title-of-entry?=1`.  Is there anyway I can pass the ID without having it appear in the URL as a parameter?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most things, there's a gem for this.

[FriendlyID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).

Installation is easy and you'll be up and running in minutes. Give it a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

Ususally you'll want to to save this part in the database `title-of-entry` (call the field `slug` or something`). Your model could look something like this:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_validation :set_slug

  def set_slug
    self.slug = self.title.parameterize
  end

  def to_param
    self.slug
  end

end
```

Now your generated routes look like this: `/entries/title-of-entry`

To find the corresponding entries you'll have to change your controller:

```
# instad of this
@entry = Entry.find(params[:id]

# use this
@entry = Entry.find_by_slug(params[:id])
```

**Update**

A few things to bear in mind:

1. You'll have to make sure that `slug` is unique, otherwise `Entry.find_by_slug(params[:id])` will always return the first entry with this slug it encounters.
2. `Entry.find_by_slug(params[:id])` will not raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception, but instead just return `nil`. Consider using `Entry.find_by_slug!(params[:id])`.
3. If you really want your routes to look like this `/title-of-entry`, you'll probably run into problems later on. The router might get you unexpected results if a entry slug looks the same as another controller's name.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed suggestion @Wukerplank, I was messing around with this last night and couldn't quite get things to work.  I would always get directed to the same `entry` no matter which `id` I was passing in.  I'm sure with more time and hacking I could have gotten things to work as you suggested, but for the sake of ease of not dealing with slug/title problems, I'm going to go with the gem.  You definitely deserve an upvote for this though, thanks again!